# SQL UNION or similar to supply missing absent rows? (Take two)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Given the two tables:

```
T_A

Key_A   A_1
1       A
2       B
3       C

T_B

Key_B    Key_A  B_1
10       1      X
10       2      Y
10       3      Z
20       1      D
20       2      E
30       1      L
```

I want to produce the following output set

```
T_X

Key_B   Key_A   A_1    B_1
10      1       A      X
10      2       B      Y
10      3       C      Z
20      1       A      D
20      2       B      E
20      3       C      NULL   <-- Missing row to also be returned
30      1       A      L
30      2       B      NULL   <-- MRTABR
30      3       C      NULL   <-- MRTABR
```

The following SQL samples supplied in (Take 1)

```
select distinct T_B.Key_B, T_A.Key_A, T_A.A_1
from T_B
cross join T_A

select sq.Key_B, T_A.Key_A, T_A.A_1
from (select distinct Key_B from T_B) sq
cross join T_A
```

Both worked very well if Column T_B.B_1 was not required in the result set.

How do I modify the SQL to now include T_B.B_1?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select distinct b.Key_B, a.Key_A, a.A_1, b1.B_1
from T_A a cross join (select key_b from T_B) b
left join T_B b1 on b1.Key_B = b.Key_B and b1.Key_A = a.Key_A;
```

edit: since Access2k doesn't supprt `cross join` the query can be rewritten as:

```
select distinct c.Key_B, c.Key_A, c.A_1, B1.B_1 
from (
    select a.Key_A, a.A_1, b.Key_B 
    from T_A a, (select key_b from T_B) b
) c 
left join T_B b1 on B1.Key_B = c.Key_B and B1.Key_A = c.Key_A ;
```

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI I've added a version that works with Access 2010.

Comment: Tested and verified on Access 2010

Comment: Works as expected for viewing records/reporting.  But if I use the query on a form then it appears the fields are not bound back to the database.  Can I accomplish this by using sub queries in Access?

Comment: Some testing in Access 2010 shows that even the simplest of cross joins cause the data to become unbound.

Comment: @WalterZAMBOTTI I don't know if it's possible to get it to be bound - I don't know Access that well. You could post this part as a new question and maybe someone who knows Access can take a look at it.